# Print Sum of each column with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with four fields seperated by a tab.
Field1   Field2   Field3   Field4 , under each field are a column of numbers. I want to print the sum of each column if possible.. I would like to start off with this and enter the sums below.

```
awk 'BEGIN {  
  print "Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4"
  print "---------------------------------"
}' sum1 sum2 sum3 sum4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cat sum.awk
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" 
        print "Field1", "Field2", "Field3", "Field4"
        print "------", "------", "------", "------" }

{ sum1 += $1; sum2 += $2; sum3 += $3; sum4 += $4; }

END { print sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4 }

$ awk -f sum.awk sum.txt
Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4
------  ------  ------  ------
12      24      36      48
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, i am getting the error sum1: command not found when i tried that

Comment: It's easiest to put the awk code in its own file and run it like in my example. Otherwise be sure to start and end _all_ of the awk code with a single quote --- and not have any single quotes in between.