# Mathematics on output from command line

Tags: linux, awk

Is there an easy way to find the sum of the values in the first column?

[image: My command line]

If so, would this method be different from sum the column in a text file? So the first would be mathematics on command line outputs, and second would be in text files w/o opening them.

Something tells me I might need awk.

Comment: The last line of output from `wc` already contains the `total`.  So `wc whatever | tail -n 1` trivially solves the stated problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use awk to perform operations on standard input or a file. To find the sum of the first column in the output of `wc`, by piping the result to awk:

```
wc *.txt | awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
```

To find the sum of the first column in a file, by reading the file directly:

```
awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}' file
```

The awk code is simple - for every line of input, add the value of the first field so the variable `sum`. Once all of the input has been read, print the value of `sum`.

Comment: great, thank you. What about about sort files according to these columns

Comment: @Doug that's a completely separate question, which is already answered elsewhere, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4262650/2088135

Comment: @TomFenech sum of a column is also answered elsewhere e.g [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240782/print-sum-of-each-column-with-awk),[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905083/how-to-sum-a-column-in-awk),[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445020/summing-values-of-a-column-using-awk-command),etc

Comment: @JID you're right, I've voted to close as a duplicate.